# Design problem when a base client uses a base class as input and derived client uses a derived class as input

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

My goal is to have a base client use a base class as an input. I would like to be able to extend the implementation of the base client through a derived client that takes a derived class as an input.

```
struct Base
{
    int a, b, c;
    ...
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
    int d, e;
    ...
};

class BaseClient
{
public:
    BaseClient(const Base& b) : b(b)
    {}
    void processA(){...}
    void processB(){...}
    ...

private:
    Base b;
};

class DerivedClient : public BaseClient
{
public:
    DerivedClient(const Derived& d) : BaseClient(d), d(d)
    {}
    void processD(){...}
    void processE(){...}
    ...

private:
    Derived d;
};
```

The bulk of the implementation is done in the `BaseClient` so taking advantage of that is a must. The problem I am having is that the `Base` class can get accessed in two different ways in the `DerivedClient` class. Once through the `BaseClient` and another through the `Derived` class data member. What is the best design practice in this situation?

Comment: Pattern not ok. You likely need a visitor to the class hierarchy (BaseVisitor, DerivedVisitor) or something similar. Worst case, you might have `Base *b` in BaseClient which is forced to be `Derived*` in `DeriverClient` - but that's fake inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is likely not the best way to model client here, for `Base` / `Derived` is a *parameter* (type argument), not a different type. However, if you really want to solve it using inheritance, it can be solved via CRTP:

```
template<typename D>
class BaseClientImpl
{
public:
    Base& getB() { return static_cast<D*>(this)->data; }

    void processA(){ /*...*/ }
    void processB(){ /*...*/ }
    // ...

    // no private b here
};

template<typename D>
class DerivedClientImpl : public BaseClientImpl<D>
{
public:
    Base& getD() { return static_cast<D*>(this)->data; }

    void processD(){ /*...*/ }
    void processE(){ /*...*/ }
    // ...

    // no private d here
};

struct BaseData
{
    Base data;
};

struct DerivedData
{
    DerivedData;
};

using BaseClient    = BaseClientImpl<BaseData>;
using DerivedClient = DerivedClientImpl<DerivedData>;
```

---

However, if you're willing to give up on the requirement that DerivedClient inherits from BaseClient and would only like to reuse the data, then it's perhaps simpler to make it via templates and SFINAE. In this case, you only have one template client:

```
template<typename Data>
class Client
{
public:
    Client(const Data& d) : d(d) {}

    // functions that always exist:
    void processA(){ /*...*/ }
    void processB(){ /*...*/ }
    // ...

    // functions that require data to be Derived
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Derived, Data>>
    processD() { /*...*/ }

    std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Derived, Data>>
    processE() { /*...*/ }
    // ...

private:
    Data d;
};
```